spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property in angular test
Recently I upgraded the angular version from 8 to 14,  ng serve and ng builds running fine, while I run unit test cases(ng test), it gives us an error -> spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
My config files as below -
**1. tsconfig.spec.json **
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
            "jasmine",
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "test.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}

2. tsconfig.app.json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "types": []
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableIvy": false
    },
    "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"],
    "files": ["main.ts", "polyfills.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}


package.json

{
  "name": "alert-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 && ng build",
    "build:dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 && ng build --configuration=development",
    "build:uat": "ng build --configuration=uat",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:watch": "ng test --watch",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix=true",
    "e2e": "ng e2e tam-ui-e2e",
    "e2e:local": "ng e2e tam-ui-e2e-local",
    "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "test:myTest": "ng test --karma-config=src/myTest-karma.conf.js  --ts-config=src/tsconfig.myTest-spec.json --main=src/myTest-test.ts trade-alerts-management ",
    "test:myTest: local": "ng test --karma-config=src/myTest-karma.conf.js --browsers=TestRunnerChrome --watch --ts-config=src/tsconfig.myTest-spec.json --main=src/test.myTest.ts myTest-app "
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "^5.12.7",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^5.12.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.165",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.5",
    "@types/luxon": "^2.3.2",
    "@types/tinymce": "^4.6.5",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "apollo-angular": "^1.10.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.11.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "2.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "2.11.0",
    "highcharts": "10.2.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.19",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^2.4.0",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "ng-mocks": "^13.1.0",
    "ng-sidebar": "^8.1.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^11.0.2",
    "node-gyp": "^3.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.2",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"`your text`
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1002.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.62",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0"
  }
}

Since my application has many test cases failing, so now I have created another Karma test runner to run my only particular test files by running( npm run test:myTest: local), before angular upgrade unit test case was working fine however after the angular upgrade started getting error - spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

myTest-karma.conf.js

// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--headless',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--disable-translate',
                    '--disable-extensions',
                ],
            },
            TestRunnerChrome: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--disable-translate',
                    '--disable-extensions',
                ],
            },
        },
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true,
        captureTimeout: 210000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000,
    });
};


tsconfig.myTest-spec.json

{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/myTest-spec",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
            "jasmine",
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "myTest-test.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "app/myapp/components/link/**/*.spec.ts",
        "app/shared/services/links/myapp/**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}


test.myTest.ts


import './test/polyfill';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

// And load the modules.
const relativeFolderPaths = [
    'app/myTest/components/link',
    'src/app/shared/services/links/strategies/myTest'
];

context
    .keys()
    .filter((filePath: string) => {
        return relativeFolderPaths.find(path => filePath.includes(path));
    })
    .map(context);



If anyone has any suggestions really appreciate it.
